# Is it possible to combine two sequences associatively?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I want to device a way to combine two sequences into one so that the operation preserves the order of elements within one sequence and is associative: $\left(A\bigoplus B\right)\bigoplus C =  A\bigoplus\left(B\bigoplus C\right)$.

It is easy to prove that $A\bigoplus B$ can't contain $A$ or $B$ with any density (the fraction of elements from $A$ in the first $N$ elements over $N$ doesn't converge).

However, is there any way to define such an operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Let $f(n)$ denote the index of $a_n$ in $A\oplus B$. Consider where the elements of $A$ end up in the two triple operations.

On the left, $a_n$ is sent to $f(f(n))$, and on the right it’s sent to $f(n)$. Thus we’d need to have $f(f(n))=f(n)$, but that’s impossible since the required injectivity of $f$ then implies $f(n)=n$.